# Datastax 5.0.3 Solr Node Stucks SecondaryIndexManagement While Being Started

Tags: solr, datastax, datastax-enterprise

When i tried to restart datastax solr nodes, it did not being up. There is no load, no disk io. When i run nodetool tpstats, i see that secondary index management tasks pending. I also checked solr cores in solr http api. I see that some of my cores is missed. Can anybody help me?

```
Pool Name                    Active   Pending      Completed   Blocked  All time blocked
MutationStage                     0         0            430         0                 0
ViewMutationStage                 0         0              0         0                 0
ReadStage                         0         0             65         0                 0
RequestResponseStage              0         0            268         0                 0
ReadRepairStage                   0         0              5         0                 0
CounterMutationStage              0         0              0         0                 0
MiscStage                         0         0              0         0                 0
CompactionExecutor                0         0            157         0                 0
MemtableReclaimMemory             0         0             49         0                 0
PendingRangeCalculator            0         0             36         0                 0
GossipStage                       0         0          19440         0                 0
SecondaryIndexManagement          1         3              6         0                 0
HintsDispatcher                   0         0              0         0                 0
MigrationStage                    0         0              0         0                 0
MemtablePostFlush                 0         0             49         0                 0
ValidationExecutor                0         0              0         0                 0
Sampler                           0         0              0         0                 0
MemtableFlushWriter               0         0             49         0                 0
InternalResponseStage             0         0              0         0                 0
AntiEntropyStage                  0         0              0         0                 0
CacheCleanupExecutor              0         0              0         0                 0

Message type           Dropped
READ                         0
RANGE_SLICE                  0
_TRACE                       0
HINT                         0
MUTATION                     0
COUNTER_MUTATION             0
BATCH_STORE                  0
BATCH_REMOVE                 0
REQUEST_RESPONSE             0
PAGED_RANGE                  0
READ_REPAIR                  0
```

Comment: Thanks for posting the output of `tpstats` can you also include `nodetool compactionstats` and `nodetool status`?

Comment: @markc "nodetool compactionstats" result is there is no pending compaction. When i try to nodetool status on same node i see the node is up. but when i try to nodetool status on other nodes i see the solr node is down. I disabled gossip and renable it. The result is same. I also tried so many times to restart cassandra.

Comment: I have seen on many occasions nodes take some time to build secondary indexes. What is your data size on this keyspace / table feeding the solr core? `nodetool status` can give size of the data (from a UN node)

Comment: @markc Datasize in my Solr DC per node has 80GB.

Comment: I should think the secondary index rebuild would have finished by now? Is the node now saying "UN" in `nodetool status` ?

Comment: @markc it was finished and the node says it was up. But still when i tried to run nodetool status on different node it says the node is down. Seing that the node recognized down from other nodes, i decided to restart the node, the node is still stuck at SecondaryIndexManagement state. By the way, i have no seconday indexes except SolrIndexes.

Comment: user2599860 you can use ttop to grab a thread dump from the node to see what its busy doing: https://github.com/aragozin/jvm-tools/blob/master/sjk-core/COMMANDS.md#ttop-command. For example: `java -jar sjk-plus.0.4.1.jar ttop -s 127.0.0.1:7199 -o CPU` check the front page for that github repo there will be a link to download the tool from bintray

Comment: @markc thanks for your effort so much. our datacenter changed one of our raid 1 disk and that problem solved.

Comment: glad to hear it worked out for you. So it was a i/o problem in the end, meaning slow i/o slow index rebuild? Theres a useful tool here for checking disk i/o. Not used it much myself but highly recommended from some field guys I know: http://www.planetcassandra.org/blog/getting-started-with-fio/

Answer (score 0):

Check the cassandra log files from all hosts and see what they're saying.

Answer (score 0):

It is not unusual to see a node take some time to do a secondary index build after it is bootstrapped or rebuilt (depending how its brought into a cluster).

A secondary index should not need to fully rebuild on a normal restart though.

It does depend on a lot of things such as schema, data size as well as underlying OS resources. You can view index rebuilding through OpsCenter or using `nodetool` commands such as `tpstats` and `compactionstats`.

Some doc links:

https://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra/3.0/cassandra/tools/toolsTPstats.html

https://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra/3.0/cassandra/tools/toolsCompactionStats.html